# WordPress JSON API AUTH with PHP Curl

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working with wordpress and using this plugin `https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/` for JSON API Auth and I am trying to return success with curl in PHP but whenever I run the code I am getting `{"status":"error","error":"Invalid username and\/or password."}`

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username="abcd"&password="abcd"',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
?>
```

But when I put this in the browser url `https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username=abcd&password=abcd` I am getting success
`{"status":"ok","cookie":"xyz","cookie_name":"xyzxyz","user":{"id":1,"username":"abcd","nicename":"abcd","email":"abcd@abcd.com","url":"","registered":"2020-09-10 10:42:41","displayname":"abcd","firstname":"abcd","lastname":"abcd","nickname":"abcd","description":"","capabilities":{"administrator":true},"avatar":null}}`

Can you help me what I am doing wrong with curl in PHP?

Original version of CURLOPT_URL that I have used in code

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username="'.$this->input->post('email').'"&password="'.$this->input->post('password').'"',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the " from the cURL url query string. The WordPress PHP handling your request would read your username as `"abcd"` instead of `abcd` as you are trying to achieve.

```php
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username="abcd"&password="abcd"'
```

Should be

```php
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username=abcd&password=abcd'
```

Comment: I have edited the question, can you check at the bottom of the question?

Comment: @Thor You still have the double quotes in the url that should not be there.

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?username=' . $this->input->post('email') . '&password=' . $this->input->post('password');`


As stated above by @Jonnix you still have those double quotes which I have removed for you.